# localStorage is not maintaining jquery click function effects on page refresh

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I am pulling in a list of employee names from a php array and displaying it on an html page. When an employee name is clicked (via jQuery), their name turns red (via css). Right now I have a function using localStorage as I am attempting to maintain the red state of clicked employee's on page refresh or regardless of which user views the page but as of right now when I refresh the page, the red font goes back to normal as if it has not been clicked.

I have tried using localStorage in a jQuery function to maintian the state based off the employee's id# being pulled in from a PHP array and displayed in HTML.

HTML/PHP

```
 <td>
      <span class="EmpFullName" id="<?php echo trim($data['Id']);?>"><strong>
      <?php echo $data['EmpFullName'];?></strong><br></span>
 </td>
```

jQuery

```
        $( document ).ready(function() {
        let ls = window.localStorage;
        let storeKey = 'item-clicked';

        $('.EmpFullName').click(function() {
            $(this).toggleClass('clicked');

            if(ls)
            {
                let str = ls.getItem(storeKey), arr;
                if(str)
                {
                    try{
                        arr = JSON.parse(str);
                    }
                    catch(e){
                    };
                }
                if(!Array.isArray(arr))
                {
                    arr=[];
                }

                let clicked = $(this).hasClass('clicked');
                let index = arr.indexOf(this.id);
                if(clicked)
                {
                    if(index === -1)
                    {
                        arr.push(this.id);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if(index > -1)
                    {
                        arr.splice(index, -1);
                    }
                }
                ls.setItem(storeKey, JSON.stringify(arr));
            }
        });

        let str = ls ? ls.getItem(storeKey) : '';
        if(str)
        {
            let arr;
            try{
                arr = JSON.parse(str);
            }
            catch(e){
            }

            if(Array.isArray(arr))
            {
                arr.forEach(function(id)
                {
                    $('#' + id).toggleClass('clicked');
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

CSS

```
 .clicked{
        color: red;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the way you try to get the ID attribute.
`this.id` is undefined, you should use `$(this).attr('id')`.

Also when removing an element from array, you should use `arr.splice(index, 1);` instead of `arr.splice(index, -1);`, as the second arguments means "how many elements to remove".

Regarding general code style I recommend you use the [return early pattern](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/18454/should-i-return-from-a-function-early-or-use-an-if-statement).

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. I changed  `let index = arr.indexOf(this.id);` and ` let index = arr.indexOf(this.id);` to -> ` let index = arr.indexOf($(this).attr('id'));` and `arr.push($(this).attr('id'));` ... is this what you meant?

Comment: Yes, exactly like this. After this change your code works fine for me.

Comment: can you please post the code you are using? I am still having errors... sorry :(

Comment: I see, so this is still not working for me. You are using two html tags to simulate to employee's with different id's. For some reason the jQuery is not recognizing that each employee has their own id's and is not performing the localStorage. hmmmmmmmm

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195361/discussion-between-trs7-and-jakub-kisielewski).